# Form built with FormBuilder is not updated after Service subscribe

Tags: angular

My form is displayed correctly, although the data from the Service is not being applied to the form controls when `this.getUser(+id);` is executed and there are no errors on Development Tools console. I can see the successful HTTP request/response via Development Tool, but can't see the update in my form.

What is wrong with my code?

Component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { NotificationsService } from 'angular2-notifications';

import { UsersService } from '../../core/services/users.service';

import { User } from '../../shared/interfaces/user';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './users-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users-form.component.scss'],
    providers: [UsersService]
})
export class UsersFormComponent implements OnInit {

  userForm: FormGroup;
  user: User = {
    name: '',
    username: '',
    roleId: 3
  };

  formMode = 'Cadastro';

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private usersService: UsersService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private notification: NotificationsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.buildForm();
    if (id) {
      this.formMode = 'Edição';
      this.getUser(+id);
    }
  }

  getUser(id: number) {
    this.usersService.getUserById(id)
      .subscribe((user: User) => {
        this.user = user;
      },
      (err) => console.log(err));
  }

  buildForm() {
    this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: [this.user.name, Validators.required],
      username: [this.user.username, Validators.required],
      roleId: [this.user.roleId, Validators.required]
    });
  }

  submit({ value, valid }: { value: User, valid: boolean }) {

    value.id = this.user.id;

    if (value.id) {
      this.usersService.update(value)
        .subscribe((res: User) => {
          if (res) {
            this.router.navigate(['/users']);
            this.notification.success('Sucesso!', 'Registro atualizado.');
          } else {
            this.notification.error('Erro!', 'Registro não atualizado.');
          }
        },
        (err) => console.log(err));
    } else {
      this.usersService.insert(value)
        .subscribe((res: User) => {
          if (res) {
            this.router.navigate(['/users']);
            this.notification.success('Sucesso!', 'Cadastro realizado.');
          } else {
            this.notification.error('Erro!', 'Cadastro não realizado.');
          }
        },
        (err) => console.log(err));
    }
  }
}
```

Component.html

```
<div class="animated fadeIn">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <strong>Usuário</strong>
          <small>{{formMode}}</small>
        </div>
        <div class="card-block">
          <form [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(userForm)" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name">Nome</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Informe o nome" formControlName="name">
              <div class="alert alert-danger" [hidden]="userForm.controls.name">Campo Nome requerido</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="login">Login</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Informe o login" formControlName="username">
              <div class="alert alert-danger" [hidden]="userForm.controls.username">Campo Login requerido</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="role">Perfil</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="role" formControlName="roleId">
                <option value="1">Supervisor</option>
                <option value="2">Analista</option>
                <option value="3">Inspetor</option>
              </select>
              <div class="alert alert-danger" [hidden]="userForm.controls.roleId">Campo Perfil requerido</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!userForm.valid">Salvar</button>
              <button [routerLink]="['/users']" class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Cancelar</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/.col-->
  </div>
  <!--/.row-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close. But you'll need to update the form using the new values when they become available. When you instantiate the form using the following:

`name: [this.user.name, Validators.required],`

You are only telling the form to pre-populate the `name` property with the value of `this.user.name`, which hasn't yet resolved (I'm guessing). Its not a binding, just an initial value. And in this case, your form is being instantiated faster than your `getUser()` function is retrieving the user data.

The easiest thing you can do is wait to build the form until your API call has resolved.

```js
getUser(id: number) {
    this.usersService.getUserById(id)
      .subscribe((user: User) => {
        this.user = user;

        // Now your form will have access to the correct data
        this.buildForm();
      },
      (err) => console.log(err));
  }
```

In more complex scenarios, you may need to loop through data and merge multiple subscriptions. In those situations you can instantiate the form with blank values and then update the values as your API calls come in.

```js
getUser(id: number) {
    this.usersService.getUserById(id)
      .subscribe((user: User) => {
        this.user = user

                // Update the Form Values
                if (this.userForm) {
                    this.userForm.get('name').setValue(this.user.name);
                    this.userForm.get('username').setValue(this.user.username);
                    this.userForm.get('roleID').setValue(this.user.roleID);
                }
      },
      (err) => console.log(err));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to @joshrathke answer, the following should save you a few more lines of code.

You can choose to use `.patchValue()` directly:

```
getUser(id: number) {
  this.usersService.getUserById(id).subscribe(user => {
      this.user = user;
      this.userForm.patchValue(this.user);
    },
    (err) => console.log(err)
  );
}
```

If your emission's interface from your `.subscribe()` method is similar to `:user` interface,  you can also choose to use `.setValue()`.

```
getUser(id: number) {
  this.usersService.getUserById(id).subscribe(user => {
      this.user = user;
      this.userForm.setValue(this.user);
    },
    (err) => console.log(err)
  );
}
```